# How would one prove that a linear combination of convex functions is also convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

As above, how would one mathematically prove that a linear combination of convex functions is also convex?

We know a function defined on a convex set $S$ is convex if:

$$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$$

where $t$ is from $0$ to $1$

We must prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i(x)$ is also convex given a bunch of functions $f_1, f_2$ etc.

---

How do i approach this problem? I could say the following:

$tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)+tg(x_1)+(1-t)g(x_2)=t(f(x_1)+g(x_1))+(1-t)(f(x_2)+g(x_2))$

$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)+g(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\leq t(f(x_1)+g(x_1))+(1-t)(f(x_2)+g(x_2))$

Is this how we show it?

---

Secondly, how would we prove the same thing for a concave function? Isn't it just adding a - sign? How would i mathematically prove it?

Comment: As for the concavity: how did you define concave functions? Why would you want to approach it differently in any way than convex functions?

Comment: Are the coefficients $a_i$ all non-negative?

Answer (score 8):

In general your statement is false. The function $f(x)=x^2$ is convex, while $-f$ is not convex. It is true if you consider so-called conical combinations, i.e. all coefficients are supposed to be nonnegative.

The proof is trivial bacause it is enough to multiply the inequalities by nonnegative scalars and sum them up.

Comment: This suggests another question ... How could one describe the set of linear combinations  (with real coefficients, non necessarily nonnegative ones) of convex functions ?

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

You should assume the coefficients positive.
Your sum is finite, so you just need to prove that
$$a_1f_1+a_2f_2$$ is convexe.

$$a_i>0.$$

Comment: This is obviously false. Inequalities  are not preserved by linear combinations.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It is true if the $a_i$s are positives.